# Problem with the tree command

Tags: apt, snap, tree

Previously I had installed the `tree` command with `apt` and it worked just fine, but then I formatted my PC and used `snap` because i thought is was the same thing. Now the command outputs weird strings when a directory has a name with "weird" ASCII chars, like `~` .

How can I fix the command? Do I have to reinstall the command? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I'm using Elementary OS.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. Could you provide the output you're seeing? Maybe include some info about the snap version you're using and which distro/release you're on.

Comment: It prints `Gui\303\243o\ ` instead of `Guião`.
When i use `snap version` it prints:
snap        2.37.4+18.04.1
snapd       2.37.4+18.04.1
series      16
elementary  5.0
kernel      4.15.0-46-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you found a bug with that snap.

If you would like to use the snap, consider contacting the publisher directly to file a bug (however I'm not sure that developer is still with Canonical and the email listed is para.siva [at] canonical.com). Alternatively, you might try posting on https://forum.snapcraft.io/

If you don't care about using a snap vs deb, just uninstall the snap (`sudo snap remove tree`) and install it with apt (`sudo apt install tree`).

If you would like a hacky wordaround. Install the deb with apt, then immediately remove it. This worked for me, and I believe it's because it installs some missing shared libraries, that probably should be bundled with the snap.